# Animation in sequence in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote this code to make some animations, and it is working perfectly:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $("div[id$='-1']").length; i++) {
            $("div[data-order="+ i +"]").css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({
                top : '0%',
                opacity: 1 
            }, {
                duration : 800,
                easing : 'linear'
            });
    };
```

but when i wanted to display it in order with some delay with setTimeout it doesn't work any more!

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $("div[id$='-1']").length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div[data-order="+ i +"]").css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({
                top : '0%',
                opacity: 1 
            }, {
                duration : 800,
                easing : 'linear'
            });
        }, 1000);
    };
```

Comment: try putting your loop inside the set time out together with your code for animation .

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't stop the loop from going. Basically every iteration will have the same `setTimeout` and go off all at once.

Comment: @JF-Mechs that way still the animation displaying in the same time, i wanted to make some delay so the order could be remarkable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this .. And Instead of for loop you can use `.each()`

```
$("div[id$='-1']").each(function(index){
  setTimeout(function() {
            $("div[data-order="+ index +"]").css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({
                top : '0%',
                opacity: 1 
            }, {
                duration : 800,
                easing : 'linear'
            });
        }, 1000 * index);
});
```

Comment: @G.Mab You're totally Welcome :) .. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Use math:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  // ...
}, 1000 * i);
```

Comment: exact :)) that was my mistake !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()`, `.delay()`, `.promise()`

```
var order = $("div[data-order]");
order.queue("order", $.map(order, function(el) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(el).delay(1000).css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"})
           .animate({
                top : '0%',
                opacity: 1 
            }, {
                duration : 800,
                easing : 'linear'
            }).promise().then(next);

  }
})).dequeue("order")
```